# How do I convert these for loops to range based loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Here is the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort1
Earlier when I started solving problems on HackerRank, I solved it using simple for loops as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void partition(vector <int> ar){
    vector <int> left;
    vector <int> right;
    int p=ar.at(0);
    for (int i=1;i<ar.size();i++){
        if (ar.at(i)<=p) left.push_back(ar.at(i));
        else if (ar.at(i)>p) right.push_back(ar.at(i));
    }
    for (int j=0;j<left.size();j++) cout <<left.at(j)<< " ";
    cout << ar.at(0)<< " ";
    for (int j=0;j<right.size();j++) cout <<right.at(j)<< " ";

}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> num;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        num.push_back(temp);
    }
    partition(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Today I came to know about range based for loops so I wanted to find out if HackerRank compiler supports them. I made the following changes in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void partition(vector <int> ar){
    vector <int> left;
    vector <int> right;
    int p=ar.at(0);
    for (int i=1;i<ar.size();i++){
        if (ar.at(i)<=p) left.push_back(ar.at(i));
        else if (ar.at(i)>p) right.push_back(ar.at(i));
    }
    for (int j : left) cout <<left.at(j)<< " ";
    cout << ar.at(0)<< " ";
    for (int j : right) cout <<right.at(j)<< " ";
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> num;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        num.push_back(temp);
    }
    partition(num);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault for both the cases.

```
Testcase# 1

Input

5 4 5 3 7 2

Your Output

~ no response on stdout ~

Expected Output

3 2 4 5 7

Compiler Message

Segmentation Fault

Error

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check Aborted (core dumped)

Testcase# 2

Input

9 2 10 3 7 9 4 6 12 8

Your Output

2

Expected Output

2 10 3 7 9 4 6 12 8

Compiler Message

Segmentation Fault

Error

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am using range based loops or HackerRank doesn't supports them. This page (https://www.hackerrank.com/environment) says they use g++ 4.7.3, C0x Mode. Thanks

Comment: Note: `at` performs bounds-checking, which isn't required here.

Comment: the only difference between your rather long snippets is `for (int j : right) cout <<right.at(j)<< " ";
` vs. `for (int j=0;j<left.size();j++) cout <<left.at(j)<< " ";`. Obviously, it is this difference that causes the problem. It would be great if, going forward, you identify the difference and reduce your question to the simplest possible form.

Comment: `if (ar.at(i)<=p) ...  else if (ar.at(i)>p)` statement makes no sence; if `(ar.at(i)<=p)` is not satisfied, than `(ar.at(i)>p)` is certainly satisfied...

Comment: @DyP `[]` probably performs bounds-checking as well, unless you're generating optimized code.  (It does with the two compilers I regularly use, anyway, with the usual non-optimized options.)  On the other hand, if there isn't a try...catch to do something special with the case, `at` isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range-based loops return the values of the vector, not the indices.

```
//This:
for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i) {
   std::cout << ar.at(i) << std::endl;
}
//means this:
for (int val : ar) {
   std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Notice the lack of `at`.

Answer (score 3):

The variable used for the range-based for loops is *not* the index, it's the actual value. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which also shows how range-based for loops are working.

You also forgot to change your first loop.

Answer (score 2):

Line

```
left.at(j)
```

should be replaced with

```
j
```

j is now not an index, but a value